# CSS How to Create a Responsive Line on Either Side of a Fixed Centered Logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've been trying to get what the title says to work for hours now. Here's a screenshot of what it should look like: http://postimg.org/image/4d4nyzzcl/

So the logo in the center should have a fixed size, but the lines on either side should be fluid. When the browser's window is made smaller, the logo stays the same size but the lines get shorter.

As you can see from the screenshot this is going in a div with a background-image. Also I'm using bootstrap as a base. I'm not going to post what I tried because it turned into such a mess and I would probably be laughed at...

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it, been trying to get to a solution for way too long.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this Bootstrap grid example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "Bootstrap-friendly" approach using the Bootstrap grid..

```
<div class="wide">
    <div class="col-xs-5 line"><hr></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 line"><hr></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wide {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-image:url('/assets/example/bg_8.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}

.wide img {
  width:100%;
}

.logo {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:800;
  font-size:14pt;
  padding:25px;
  text-align:center;
}

.line {
  white-space:no-wrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
```

http://bootply.com/108614

Comment: Hey there, thanks so much for the reply. Ok so your solution works well on big resolutions, it just breaks when we start re-sizing the window. I'm using an image as the logo and because the image stays the same size (which is good) but it's in a responsive div so the div gets smaller and the logo just sticks out the right and overlaps the right .line div. Here's a screenshot of what's happening http://postimg.org/image/6mkopffmh/

Answer (score 0):

You could use css :before and :after.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/kANS4/1/

```
    header:before {content:""; display:block; width:39%; height:1px; background:#fff;
    position:absolute; top:50%; left:1%;}
header:after {content:""; display:block; width:39%; height:1px; background:#fff;
    position:absolute; top:50%; right:1%;}
```

Additionally , I used display: table-cell for vertical centering, and relative/absolute positing for the before and after pseudo elements.

In older browsers, that don't support before and after, you won't see the white lines.  Here is a chart for browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

PS - An update to Fiddle for better margin on the inner box: http://jsfiddle.net/kANS4/3/

Comment: Hey there, thanks so much for the reply. But the problem I'm having with this solution is that the logo is responsive in your example - whereas I need mine to remain the same size. It's going to be a .png too. Do you know of a way to achieve this? I got close with the solution above, but still on smaller resolutions, because the div that the logo is in is responsive, it becomes too big for its containing div. Check it out http://postimg.org/image/6mkopffmh/ Thanks again

Comment: At that point, maybe you just place it all into a table.  With a table you can fix one TD to a certain width and have the other two TDs be fluid.  
Above layout works for round logos, I did a similar layout recently.